# 80% of tax fees in uniswap

Tags: uniswap, fees

I PUT 27 euros to uniswap and they take 6 euros in fees for PUT it in the wallet and then I want to swap my Ethereum and it says that I only have 3 euros to swap in ethereum. It’s normal that they take like around 80 or 90% on tax fees?

Comment: Uniswap on mainnet isn't intended for small amounts. As of today 2023-05-16 the Uniswap transaction fees are about 16-18 USD. Before sending a transaction you should check the fees costs. Another possible problem are scam tokens, if you have interacted with one you could lose all your funds.